# How long does it take to get established as a real estate agent?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

I realize that it varies, but should 2 years (beyond real estate classes) be long enough to become self-sufficient ?

Comment: Any answers to this question will be highly regional, dependent on the real estate market in your jurisdiction. One clear point, however, is that often the real estate market is often mostly unregulated, meaning it is easy to get into, meaning many people are in it. This is a highly competitive market where you need to separate yourself in some way from entrenched competition who have experience and market presence as an advantage against new players. Simply getting your license and putting an ad in the paper will not be enough to get clients.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon   South Florida is the market.

Comment: (Well, your profile threw me off!)

Answer (score 5):

First, what is your criteria for "self-sufficient"? You know that the first level license you get is a salesperson license. You cannot work for yourself but need to work under a broker.

Your success will be a result of your networking ability and the broker's office reputation. If you are in your 20's, have a wide circle of friends, and they are at the point that they are ready to buy their first home, you have a great start. From there, building your own reputation and working to build your listings (for sales) will get you to the 2 year mark, when you can take the broker exam and open your own office.

Comment: (+1) By "self-sufficient" I'm talking just a fairly reliable $2500 per month.

Comment: Your profile shows Portland ME. The median home price is just north of $200K. A 6% commission, split between the listing agent and then your office means about $3000 to you. Your goal is about one purchase or sale per month. This is strictly based on your ability to get clients, 12 per year on average. More important, is for them to be happy enough to use the line "I know an agent that was great..." when anyone mentions they are looking to buy or sell.